# Android: Progress Dialog with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, text-to-speech, progressdialog

Since the game requires TTS, and need quite a long time to load, I would like to implement Progress Dialog (PD), as **either** in the following ways:

### Implement AsyncTask in Game Index Page:

This will show the PD, but the PD is freezed, i.e. the looping circle inside the PD is not looping.

```
    buttonC.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            new initialize_game().execute();
        }
    }); 


private class initialize_game extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> 
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {           
        dialog= new ProgressDialog(Index_game.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading!\nPlease wait...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {            
        buttonC.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_black));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Index_game.this, Game_star_intro.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0); // 0 for no animation
        Index_game.this.finish();   
        return "Done!";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("result","" +result);
        if(result!=null)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }      
    }
}
```

### AsyncTask for TTS:

Once clicked from the Game Index Page, no PD is shown until the Game is loaded fully, and at that time then the PD pops up and off for a millisecond, i.e. even worse than that above.

```
private class MainFrameTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener
{
    private Index_game_card_intro mainFrame = null;  

    public MainFrameTask(Index_game_card_intro mainFrame)
    {  
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onCancelled() 
    {  
        stopProgressDialog();  
        super.onCancelled();  
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {           
        startProgressDialog(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {            
        // setup TTS part 1.1
          mTts = new TextToSpeech(Index_game_card_intro.this, this);  // TextToSpeech.OnInitListener



        return "Done!";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        stopProgressDialog();      
    }

 // setup TTS part 2    
    @Override
    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) 
    {  
        Log.v(TAG, "Get completed message for the utteranceId " + utteranceId);  
        lastUtterance = Integer.parseInt(utteranceId);  
    }  

// setup TTS part 3 
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) 
    {  
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)  
        {  
            int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);  // <====== set speech location
            mTts.setSpeechRate((float) 0.8);
            mTts.setPitch(1.0f);
            if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED)  
            {  
                // button_header.setEnabled(false);  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                // button_header.setEnabled(true);  
                mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);  
            }  
        }     
    }    
}

// setup TTS part 4 
private void speakText()  
{  
    lastUtterance++;  
    if(lastUtterance >= loveArray.length)  
    {  
        lastUtterance = 0;  
    }  
    Log.v(TAG, "the begin utterance is " + lastUtterance);  
    for(int i = lastUtterance; i < loveArray.length; i++)  
    {  
        params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, String.valueOf(i));  
        mTts.speak(loveArray[i], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);  
        mTts.playSilence(ttsilience, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }  
}
```

### Question:

I found that the Progress Dialog does not show out when Button C in the game index is pressed. However, when the `Game_star_intro` is finally loaded, the progress dialog pops up for a very very short time and then gone.

I would like to show the ProgressDialog when it is loading up the game, not after the game is loaded then the dialog pops for a millisecond.

In this way, I have also tried to put the load TTS in `AsyncTask` inside `Game_star_intro`, yet the result is the same: the dialog just pops up for a millisecond.

Actually how should the AsyncTask be coded?? I have followed some website like this http://karanbalkar.com/2012/10/tutorial-5-custom-progressdialog-with-asynctask/

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you seen this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493528/progress-dialog-with-asynctask?rq=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't start your activity in background thread. Start it, for example, in your `onClick()` method. You should put only your expensive code in `doInBackground()`, separating it from the framework lifecycle stuff. I guess you should implement `AsyncTask` inside `Game_star_intro` class for this.

`ProgressDialog` is not showing probably because UI thread is freezed until the work is done.

Also, naming conventions in Java suggest name classes without underscores, i.e. GameStarIntro :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried moving the loading TTS in the doInBackground inside `Game_star_intro` now. Yet I tested and found that when pressing the buttonC in the game index page, it hangs for the loading time, and then when the `Game_star_intro` is loaded, the progress dialog just pops out for a second and the page is ready for speaking.  UI thread is freezed?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads
"Specifically, if everything is happening in the UI thread, performing long operations such as network access or database queries will block the whole UI. When the thread is blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events. From the user's perspective, the application appears to hang." I assume you may not see your dialog because UI thread is blocked, i.e. freezed.

Comment: yes i now figure out what you mean. put in this way, in my ProgressDialog (PD), there is an looping imageview. if i put the AsyncTask at game_index page, the ProgressDialog will appear but the imageview will not loop. Yet if I put in the `Game_star_intro`, the PD even does not appear until TTS is loaded, and then PD pops out and off in a milisecond. So, it seems loading the TTS blocks the UI

Comment: So, I guess, this should be marked as answered? Problems with TTS deserves a different question, I think, with TTS code posted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly from your question, loading of the `Game_star_intro` activity takes a lot of time because you use TTS in creation of this activity. The code you use is wrong. ProgressDialog from `Index_game` won't be shown when another activity is running (or is being created). You should use `AsyncTask` in `Game_star_intro` activity and use TTS there. In `Index_game` just start `Game_star_intro`:

```
buttonC.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Index_game.this, Game_star_intro.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});
```

And in `Game_star_intro` something like this

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    new TTLTask().execute();
}

private class TTLTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {           
        dialog= new ProgressDialog(Index_game.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading!\nPlease wait...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {            
        //... TTS code
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("result","" +result);
        if(dialog.isShown())
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I have tried implemented in this way by switching the AsyncTask as loading the TTS in the `doInBackground` inside `Game_star_intro`. I tested and found that when pressing the buttonC in the game index page, it hangs for the loading time, and then when the `Game_star_intro` is loaded, the progress dialog just pops out for a second and the page is ready for speaking.

Comment: I guess the problem is not in this AsyncTask, but somewhere else. Creation of TextToSpeach is fast. That's why PD just pops up for a second. Try to find the reason before the place, where you execute the task.